# Why was the desktop operating sytem not included this year?

Tags: feature-request, survey-2017

Why were the desktop OS stats dropped from the report this year? Which desktop OS that developers use *is by far the most important info to me*. :-(

I **really** wanted to know how Linux fared this year compared to Windows. Can it still be included? *Please?* :-)

Comment: [Voting on Meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). The down vote likely indicates disagreement.

Comment: I'm not sure how important it is.  The only importance it holds for me nowadays is I have to remember that my coworkers aren't working in a case-sensitive filesystem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were a lot of questions, and this was one of them, that were cut simply to save time & cognitive load for the respondents.  We're definitely considering putting this one back in for 2018.

One thing I'm curious about:  would anyone here change to a different OS if they saw that a lot of other devs were using it?  (Could be switching to an entirely different OS, e.g. Linux --> Windows, or switching flavors/versions, e.g. Windows 7 --> Windows 10.)  Are there any CTO-types out there who would use these data to make recommendations on a standard toolset for their developers?

Comment: I know I won't switch OSes (7 -> 10) for any reason. Unless I somehow miraculously take up developing indie games on a HoloLens (its the future man). In which case I'd probably buy *a second machine* for it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend putting it back. It is important for the industry to know which is the preferred operating system of developers.

Comment: I don't know about CTO types, but there are definitely desktop-operating-system-creator types who would like to use this data to help make our offerings more useful to developers.

Comment: Whenever I did switch it was for that reason.  I saw a lot of developers using Linux, I saw a lot of servers using LInux, and software I was interested in developing with always included Linux instructions.

Now, though, I can't see myself switching back.

Comment: Yes, it's an essential question. Probably put it out there on the top as one of the first questions.